# Changing package to an android application published

Tags: android, google-play

I am working in the 1.1 version of an app which first version (1.0) was made for a consulting company. That company published the app in Play using a package like com.thatcompany.mycompany. Our problem is that currently we want to deliver the 1.1 version as com.mycompany. As long as I know if we try to do that (change the package) our app don't be perceived for Play market as an upgrade of the last version but as a different application. Does exist some way to do package change and still being the same application on Play in order to the user be encouraged to update? Thanks.

Comment: you can not change pkg name of existing app.

Comment: See http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html for details

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you can't.
Your app is signed.
Signing uses your keystore and the package name.
If you change any of these the Play store will recognize it as a different application.
I believe it has something to do with security.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.
An application is uniquely identified in the market place with its package name, therefore you cannot change the package name anymore (the same goes with the key).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change either the package name or keystore used to sign your app.

To confirm what everyone else says, you CANNOT modify your package once your app has been published.